# Android HttpClient Garbage Collection Issue

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, apache-httpclient-4.x

**EDIT BELOW**

I'm writing an application to scrape content from web pages, however I'm running into an issue where getting comparatively larger (but still quite small) pages is slamming the garbage collection of my device and taking quite a while to finish.

Here's my code:

```
// Execute URL.
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet, httpContext);

// Get response data.
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
String result = "";
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    result += line;
}
httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

And here is an example of a URL that causes the issue:
http://mangafox.me/manga/one_piece/

The offending line seems to be the httpClient.execute(httpGet, httpContext) line.

Here is a small snippet of what my log quickly fills up with:

```
GC_CONCURRENT freed 3275K, 46% free 4159K/7700K, paused 40ms+14ms, total 102ms
WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 60ms
GC_CONCURRENT freed 665K, 47% free 4087K/7700K, paused 14ms+18ms, total 106ms
WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 94ms
```

I imagine due to my inexperience there is a large amount of optimisation my application is missing, considering my phone's browser is capable of loading the URL just fine.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

I've improved my code through the use of a StringBuilder, which I was previously mistaken to believe would be used automatically by Java. My application fuctions much better now as a result.

My code is now as follows:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    builder.append(line);
}
```

Are there any other improvements I could make with regards to the line = reader.readLine() line?

Comment: on a side note, if you do something like `String a = "foo" + 3 + "bar"`, a StringBuffer will be used, but just across one line.

Comment: why do you use a buffered reader and `readLine`? your lines are of all sort of length, why would it make sense to use that?

Comment: Between you and me I just copied an example for that segment of code. Could you recommend me the better way to do it please?

Comment: since you use HttpClient, there is the excellent EntityUtils: `String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());`